# MySQL creating table error

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, create-table

I'm getting this error while trying to create a table

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'not null,     PRIMARY KEY(nomeA),     FOREIGN KEY(nomeA)
>   REFERENCES Alimento(nomeA))' at line 4

and here's the code

```
create table Alimento
    (nomeA varchar(255) not null unique,
    vegetariano tinyint(1) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(nomeA));

create table Simples
    (nomeA varchar(255) not null,
    calgramas numeric(5,2) not null,
    tipo varchar not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(nomeA),
    FOREIGN KEY(nomeA) REFERENCES Alimento(nomeA));


create table Agregado
    (nomeA varchar(255) not null,
    calorias numeric(5,2) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(nomeA),
    FOREIGN KEY(nomeA) REFERENCES Alimento(nomeA));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the length of your `tipo` column

```
tipo varchar(100) not null
            ^^^^^---------------add something like this
```

If you use a SQL Tool like *Mysql Workbench* then such errors will be highlighted and are easy to find.

Comment: Argh, I feel so dumb, I guess it's cause I've been working so late lately, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table Alimento
    (nomeA varchar(255) not null unique primary key,
    vegetariano tinyint(1) not null);
```

Beside this, I would recommend an INT field ID as primary key, it will make things easier if the project grows ...

Comment: what is the main difference between specifing a primary key right after it's type or in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
tipo varchar(20) not null

and would like to suggest that for table Alimento you have already used primary key for nomeA then no need to define it as not null unique
```

Comment: I thought there was no need but yet was not sure, so there's no need to have "unique" when you define something as primary?